# UFT 14.0 GetCellData is not working

Tags: uft

The **getcelldata** call below runs on UFT 12.02 while on UFT 14
 it does not work :

```
NomColonne=Browser("trucmuche").Page("Page_1").WebTable("NomCol_Tab1").GetCellData(1,2)"
```

the error is : `Unspecified runtime error`

The environment is the same in both cases

Has anyone encountered this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: A quick web search found several possible causes but more information would be needed. Are you testing a web application or a desktop app? If web, which browser?

Comment: its a web application on internet explorer 11.0.110

Comment: The problem is with WebTable on UFT 14 to fix the bug : EnableWebRoleBasedKit = 0 on Setting.Packages.WebPackage.Settings

Comment: Please add an answer with this information and then mark it as accepted. You will probably need to expand a bit on your comment to make it a good answer.